# Implementing singletons across binary modules

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, dynamic-linking, boost-log

### Background

First of all, I think this question goes beyond the C++ standard. The standard deals with multiple translation units (instantiation units) and thus multiple object modules, but does not seem to acknowledge the possibility of having multiple independently compiled and linked binary modules (i.e., `.so` files on Linux and `.dll` files on Windows). After all, the latter more of less enters into the world of [application binary interface (ABI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) that the standard leaves to implementations to consider at present.

When only a single binary module is involved, the following code snippet illustrates an elegant and portable (standard-compliant) solution to make singletons.

```
inline T& get() {
  static T var{};
  return var;
}
```

There are two things to note about this solution. First, the `inline` specifier makes the function a candidate to be included in multiple translation units, which is very convenient. Note that, the standard guarantees there is only a single instance of `get()` and the local static variable `var` in the final binary module (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)).

The second thing to note is that since C++11, initialization of static local variables is properly synchronized (see the **Static local variables** section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)). So, concurrent invocations of `get()` is fine.

Now, I try to extend this solution to the case when multiple binary modules are involved. I find the following variant works with VC++ on Windows.

```
// dllexport is used in building the library module, and
// dllimport is used in using the library in an application module.
// Usually controlled by a macro switch.
__declspec(dllexport/dllimport) inline T& get() {
  static T var{};
  return var;
}
```

**Note for non-Windows users:** `__declspec(dllexport)` specifies that an entity (i.e., a function, a class or an object) is implemented (defined) in this module and is to be referenced by other modules. `__declspec(dllimport)`, on the other hand, specifies that an entity is not implemented in this module and is to be found in some other module.

Since VC++ supports exporting and importing template instantiations (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168958)), the above solution can even be templated. For example:

```
template <typename T> inline
T& get() {
  static T var{};
  return var;
}

// EXTERN is defined to be empty in building the library module, and 
// to `extern` in using the library module in an application module.
// Again, this is usually controlled by a macro switch.
EXTERN template __declspec(dllexport/dllimport) int& get<int>();
```

As a side note, the `inline` specifier is not mandatory here. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879038/identity-of-function-template-instantiation-in-multiple-translation-units) S.O. question.

### The Question

Since there is no `__declspec(dllexport/import)` equivalents in GCC and clang, is there a way to make a variant of the above solution that works on these two compilers?

Also, in Boost.Log, I noticed the `BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT` macro (see the **Global logger objects** section [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/sources.html)). It is claimed to create singletons *even if the application consists of multiple modules*. If someone knows about the inner workings of this macro, explanations are welcome here.

Finally, if you know about any better solutions for making singletons, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain for non windows users what precisely `dllimport`/`dllexport` do and why there is an issue when using multipole .so files? Ideally, giving a simple test code.

Comment: @Lingxi Well, for the sake of design, I would ask myself if a singleton is necessary at all to achieve what you want.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In fact, I just want a convenient way to create and share an instance across multiple binary modules just like what `BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT` does.

Comment: @Lingxi Hmm. what makes `dllimport` different from a simple `extern` ?

Comment: @Walter Maybe, it prevents the module from generating a definition itself from the function body, but instead, to find a definition in another module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since there is no `__declspec(dllexport/import)` equivalents in GCC and clang, is there a way to make a variant of the above solution that works on these two compilers?

First, this is not as much a compiler-related question but rather an underlying operating system one. GCC (and supposedly clang) do support `__declspec(dllexport/import)` on Windows and basically do the same as what MSVC does with the functions and object marked this way. Basically, the marked symbol is placed in a table of exported symbols from the dll (an export table). This table can be used, for instance, when you query for a symbol in a dll in run time (see [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Along with the dll there comes an associated lib file that contains auxiliary data for linking your application with the dll. When you link your application with the library, the linker uses the lib file to resolve references to the dll symbols and compose the import table in your application binary. When the application starts, the OS (or rather the runtime loader component of the OS) uses the import table to find out what dlls your application depends on and what symbols it imports from those dlls. It then uses export tables in the dlls to resolve addresses of the referenced symbols in the dlls and complete the linking process.

The important side effect of this process is that only imported symbols are dynamically resolved and every symbol you dynamically link to is associated with a particular dll. You can have same-named symbols in multiple dlls and the application itself, and these symbols will refer to distinct entities as long as they are not exported. If they are exported, linking process will fail because of ambiguity. This makes process-wide singletons difficult on Windows. This also breaks some C/C++ language rules, because taking address of an object or function with external linkage (in the language terms) can produce different addresses in different parts of the program. On the other hand, the dlls are more self-contained and depend on the loading context in a lesser degree.

Things are significantly different on Linux and other POSIX-like OSs. When linked, for each shared object (which can be an so library or the application executable) a table of symbols is compiled. It lists both the symbols this shared object implements and the symbols it is missing. Additionally, the linker may embed into the shared object a list of other shared objects (optionally, with search paths) that could be used to resolve the missing symbols. The runtime loader includes a linker which loads the shared objects sequentially and constructs a global table of symbols comprising symbols from all shared objects. As that table is constructed, the duplicate symbols from multiple shared objects are resolved to a single implementation (as all implementations are considered equivalent, the first shared object in the load list that implements the symbol is used). Any missing symbols are also resolved as the subsequent shared objects in the link order are loaded.

The effect of this process is that each symbol with external linkage resolve to a single implementation in one of the shared objects, even if multiple shared objects implement it. This is more in line with the C/C++ language rules and makes it simpler to implement process-wide singletons. A simple function-local static variable, not marked in any special way, is enough.

Now, there are ways to influence the linking process, and in particular there are ways to limit the symbols that are exported from a shared object. The most common ways to do that are using [symbol visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and [linker scripts](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html). With these tools it is possible to achieve linking behavior very close to Windows, with all its pros and cons. Note that when you limit symbol visibility you do have to mark the symbols you intend to export from the shared object with the `visibility` [attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) or [pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Visibility-Pragmas.html#Visibility-Pragmas). There's no need to mark symbols for import though.

> Also, in Boost.Log, I noticed the `BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT` macro (see the Global logger objects section here). It is claimed to create singletons even if the application consists of multiple modules. If someone knows about the inner workings of this macro, explanations are welcome here.

Boost.Log requires to be built as a shared library when it is used from a multi-module application. This makes it possible for it to have a process-wide storage of references to global loggers declared throughout the application (the storage is implemented within the Boost.Log dll/so). When you obtain a logger declared with the `BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT` or similar macro, the storage is first looked up for the reference to the logger. If it is not found, the logger is created and a reference to it is stored back to the internal storage. Otherwise the existing reference is used. Along with reference caching, this provides performance very close to a function-local static variable.

> Finally, if you know about any better solutions for making singletons, feel free to post it as an answer.

Although this is not really an answer, you should generally avoid singletons. They are difficult to implement correctly and in a way that does not hamper performance. If you really do have to implement one then the solution similar to Boost.Log looks generic enough. Note however that with this solution it is generally not known which module created (and as such, 'owns') the singleton, so you can't unload any modules dynamically. There may be simpler ways that are case-specific, like exporting a function returning a reference to the local static object. If you want portability and support non-default symbol visibility by default, always explicitly export your symbols.